# how to create an appbar like instagram in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to implement instagram like profile page appbar in my app.
I used customscrollview and inside that sliverappbar but that is not working
so please someone can show me an example.

[image: image Link]

I want to implement follow button when someone scroll down inside profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

fist need to initialize `ScrollController`

```
ScrollController _scrollController =
          new ScrollController();
```

Then create `initState()` and add handeleScroll() method. you need to implement this based on your needs.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handleScroll();
  }
```

write dispose method to prevent recurrent builds

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(() {});
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Then create show and hide button functions

```
  void showButton() {
    setState(() {
      _show = true;
    });
  }

  void hideButton() {
    setState(() {
      _show = false;
    });
  }
```

After that create the scroll Handel controller class

```
  void handleScroll() async {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
          hideButton();
      }
      if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
          showButton();
      }
    });
  }
```

Finally, you can implement the button UI that you link.

```
        FlatButton: Visibility(
          visible: _show,
            child: FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {})));
  
}
```